# C# MySQL commit transaction is not working (Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, transactions

I have a class that will help me to connect to a database start transaction and run some queries, and once I am done with all the queries I commit/rollback the transaction.

Here is my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RM
{
    public class dbConnetionWT
    {
        //private OdbcConnection conn; 
        private static readonly string mServer = "localhost";
        private static readonly string mDatabase = "pos";
        private static readonly string mUid = "root";
        private static readonly string mPassword = "";
        private static readonly string mPort = "3306";
        private string conn_string = String.Format("server={0};user={1};database={2};port={3};password={4};", mServer, mUid, mDatabase, mPort, mPassword);
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        private MySqlTransaction trans;

        public dbConnetionWT()
        {
            this.conn = new MySqlConnection(this.conn_string);
            try
            {
                this.conn.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                Common.Alert("Database Server is not reachable", "SQL Error");
            }
        }

        public void End()
        {
            try
            {
                this.conn.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                Common.Alert("Database Server is not reachable", "SQL Error");
            }
        }


        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            this.trans = this.conn.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                this.trans.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Common.Alert(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error");
            }

        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            try
            {
                this.trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.Alert(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error");
            }


        }


        // query the data base
        public IEnumerable<T> getData<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars, Func<IDataRecord, T> transform)
        {
            using (this.conn)
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                if (pars != null)
                {
                    foreach (MySqlParameter p in pars)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        yield return transform(rdr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // query the data base
        public T getValue<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
        {
            T value;
            using (this.conn)
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                if (pars != null)
                {
                    foreach (MySqlParameter p in pars)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    object rawValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (rawValue != null)
                    {
                        value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rawValue, typeof(T));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = default(T);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Common.Alert(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error");
                    value = default(T);
                    this.trans.Rollback();
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

        public bool processQuery(string strSQL, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
        {
            bool toReturn = true;

            using (this.conn)
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {

                if (pars != null)
                {
                    foreach (MySqlParameter param in pars)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    Common.Alert(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error");
                    toReturn = false;
                    this.trans.Rollback();
                }
            }

            return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using it when running into an issue

```
 bool hasSqlError = false;
 string sql2 = " INSERT INTO products "
 + " (productUPC, productName, price, createdBy, departmentID, vendorID, productDescription) "
 + " VALUES('123', 'Name', '29.99', '1', '2', '3', 'This is a test')";

if (!dbwt.processQuery(sql2, null))
{
    hasSqlError = true;
}

if (!hasSqlError)
{
    dbwt.Commit();
    dbwt.End();
    this.Close();
}
else
{

    dbwt.Rollback();
}
```

But I keep getting an error when trying to commit `dbwt.Commit();`

here is the exception error that I get
[image]

How can I correct this issue? I don't understand why I get this error even if I open the connection in the constructor?

Comment: so I should not use `using (this.conn)`? or do I need to use it in the constructor?

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much. if you post an answer to the question I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `using (this.conn)` in the `processQuery()` method, and the `using` statement causes your connection to be closed. So the error message makes sense.

You're already closing the connection explicitly in the `End()` method, so omit the following line:

```
using (this.conn)
```

Also FWIW, you may want to make sure you close the connection after a rollback too:

```
if (!hasSqlError)
{
    dbwt.Commit();
}
else
{
    dbwt.Rollback();
}
dbwt.End();
this.Close();
```

Or, to make sure the connection is closed even in the event of an exception being thrown:

```
try
{
    if (!hasSqlError)
    {
        dbwt.Commit();
    }
    else
    {
        dbwt.Rollback();
    }
    this.Close();
}
finally
{
    dbwt.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note this code:

```
    public T getValue<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
    {
        T value;
        using (this.conn)
```

If you call `getValue<T>` at some point, once the block following

```
        using (this.conn)
```

goes out of scope, `this.conn.Dispose()` will be called, closing the connection.